# aplicar funcion solo al seleccionar items especificos en treview

Tags: python, tkinter, programación-funcional

como se puede hacer para que la función solo afecte a los subitems del primer item en el siguiente code:

ademas me gustaria saber la difenrencia entre `tag_bind` y `bind` y que argumentos tienen

```
import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import ttk

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title('HERRAMIENTA 1.0')
raiz.resizable(0, 1)
raiz.iconbitmap(r'dd.ico')
raiz.config(bg='silver', width='200', height='200')
#
framet = tk.Frame(raiz)
framet.place(x='0', y='0')
framet.config(bg='silver', cursor='pirate',relief='ridge')
#treeview
tree=ttk.Treeview(framet,style="mystyle.Treeview")
tree.config(height=22)
tree.grid(column=1,row=3,columnspan=8)


tree.insert('', 0, 'item0', text='primer item')
tree.insert('', 1, 'item1', text='segundo item')


subitems1=['primero','segundo','tercero']

for i,subitems in enumerate(subitems1):
    tree.insert('item0', i, f'subitem{i}', text=subitems)

def gg(event):
    print('gggggggggggggg')

tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>',gg)

raiz.mainloop()
```

en  `tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>',gg)` hay un tercer argumento `add` que significa?
gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tu duda principal, que además tiene que ver con tu segunda duda, ya que `tag_bind` es la solución, agrega una etiqueta común aquellos items que quieras que compartan callback:

```
import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import ttk

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title('HERRAMIENTA 1.0')
raiz.resizable(0, 1)
# raiz.iconbitmap(r'dd.ico')
raiz.config(bg='silver', width='200', height='200')

framet = tk.Frame(raiz)
framet.place(x='0', y='0')
framet.config(bg='silver', cursor='pirate',relief='ridge')

# treeview
tree=ttk.Treeview(framet,style="mystyle.Treeview")
tree.config(height=22)
tree.grid(column=1,row=3,columnspan=8)

tree.insert('', 0, 'item0', text='primer item')
tree.insert('', 1, 'item1', text='segundo item')


subitems1=['primero','segundo','tercero']

for i, subitems in enumerate(subitems1):
    tree.insert('item0', i, f'subitem{i}', text=subitems, tags=("item0"))

def gg(event):
    print('gggggggggggggg')

tree.tag_bind('item0', "<<TreeviewSelect>>", gg) 

raiz.mainloop()
```

El método `ttk.TreeView.tag_bind` no tiene mucho misterio, como su nombre indica asocia una callback a una etiqueta en concreto. Su firma es:

```
tag_bind(tagname, sequence=None, callback=None)
```

Dónde:

- **`tagname`** -> Nombre de la etiqueta objetivo.
- **`secuence`** -> es una cadena de patrones de eventos concatenados.

  Cada patrón de evento tiene la estructura `<MODIFICADOR-MODIFICADOR-TIPO-DETALLE>`:

  - El modificador  es  `"Control"`, `"Shift"`, `"Lock"`, `"Button1"`, `"Button2"`, `"Botón3"`, `"Alt"`, etc.
  - El tipo es el tipo de evento, `"Activate"`, `"Enter"`, `"ButtonPress"`, `"Button"`, `"Motion"`, `"ButtonRelease"`, `"FocusIn"`, `"MouseWheel"`, `"KeyPress"`, etc.
  - "detalle" por su parte sirve para especificar algunas cosas en eventos específicos, por ejemplo el número de botón para `ButtonPress`

  El `TreeView` dispone de tres eventos virtuales:

  - **`"<<TreeviewSelect>>"`** se genera cuando un item es seleccionado.
  - **`"<<TreeviewOpen>>"`** se genera cuando un item es abierto.
  - **`"<<TreeviewClose>>"`** se genera cuando un item es cerrado.
- **`callback`** -> Referencia al callable a llamar cuando el evento se produzca.

Por su parte el método `tkinter.ttk.TreeView.bind` no difiere realmente mucho del método `bind` de cualquier otro widget. Su firma es:

```
bind(sequence=None, func=None, add=None)
```

Los argumentos `secuence` y `func` son idénticos a `tag_bind`.

El argumento `add` es un boleano y permite especificar si el nuevo enlace substituye a los que existieran antes o se agrega. Es decir, si antes llamamos a bind para el mismo evento y widget, si `add` es `True` se llama a ambas callback, si es `False` se llama solo a la enlazada con el último `bind` que reemplaza a la anterior:

```
def gg(event):
    print('gggggggggggggg')

def hh(event):
    print('hhhhhhhhhhhhhh')

tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", gg) 
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", hh, add=True)
```

La diferencia entre `tag_bind` y `bind` es básicamente que la primera permite enlazar eventos para una determinada etiqueta (por tanto para solo algunos items de árbol) mientras que `bind` enlaza el evento para todos los items del mismo.

Comment: cuando dices "Cada patrón de evento tiene la estructura <MODIFICADOR-MODIFICADOR-TIPO-DETALLE>:" ,que significa poner el '<1>' en "tree.tag_bind('item0', '<1>', gg) "

Comment: Ups, fue un error al copiar el código lo usé simplemente para probarlo, "<Button-1>", "<ButtonPress-1>", y "<1>" son lo mismo, el mismo tipo de evento (click con botón izquierdo del ratón). Debería haber usado "<<TreeviewSelect>>".

Comment: jaja , ya decia, como caracoles funciona bien.                     Muchas gracias:)

Comment: A mi no me gusta usarlo porque es todo lo contrario a lo que se busca en Python, la legibilidad (con lo que estoy totalmente de acuerdo), si no lo sabes podrías pensar que es la tecla 1, o vete a saber que,  pero viene heredado de tk/tcl... Pero eso si, es muy cortito de escribir...XD. De nada y un saludo.